# Accord du participe passé du verbe pronominal « se libérer »

Tags: accord, verbes-pronominaux

Doit-on écrire « une place s'est libéré » ou « une place s'est libérée » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avec les verbes pronominaux, l'accord du participe passé n'est pas systématique mais il est correct de dire qu'il faut faire l'accord avec 'se libérer", ce qui donne bien:

> Une place s'est libérée

Pour ne pas se tromper, il faut savoir quel type de verbe pronominal on a. Or, "se libérer" est un verbe dit "**accidentellement** pronominal" car "libérer" existe tout seul (contrairement à "se souvenir", "s'absenter"... qui sont des verbes essentiellement pronominaux). Les verbes "essentiellement pronominaux" s'accordent toujours avec le sujet, les verbes accidentellement pronominaux s'accordent en fonction de la place du complément d'objet direct (COD).

Pour aller plus loin, "se libérer" est un verbe "accidentellement pronominal **passif**" car ce n'est pas le sujet qui fait l'action. Dans ce cas, on a bien un accord en genre et en nombre avec le sujet car "se" est COD (on peut dire "libérer quelqu'un").

Answer (score 3):

Sans hésitation, l’attribut s'accorde avec le sujet, donc :

> une place s'est libérée